# how to uninstall MinGW and make cygwin 'make' as deafult make program with gcc 3.8.1

Tags: cygwin, mingw, uninstallation

1. How to uninstall MinGW?

I have installed it for some software but now I don't use that software at all and so I need to remove the `MinGW` in order to use Cygwin for android development.

2. How to set the Cygwin 'make' file as default with `GCC 3.8.1`?

I am on windows 7 64-bit

Comment: gcc does not use make, make uses gcc. If you ensure, that the Cygwin `make` is found first in your PATH, this should be sufficient.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Answer 1:**

1. if you have used an installer, uninstall it through *program manager*
2. Remove your MinGW folder (eg. `C:/MinGW`)
3. Make sure there's no MinGW path left in `PATH` environment variable

If you haven't used an installer, you can skip *1.*, but if you have, you should check *2.* and *3.* manually.

**Answer 2:**

Do you use an IDE? If yes you can specify your make / gcc there. You can set an absolute path to the correct program too.

Comment: Note, I used an installer (mingw-get-setup), but it did not appear in program manager. So, in addition to the steps you listed, I had to manually delete the shortcuts it installed.

Answer (score 17):

We can't uninstall MinGW with program manager. Just delete the folder and the environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an uninstall.exe for Windows-10 under `C:/MinGW` which worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

just erase folder
^^
and have some snacks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).